# Input strings being treated as text objects by browser

Tags: javascript, html, string, text, output

I have a popup that displays a user's form input for review/edit prior to submission. All the information is being retrieved and displayed with no problem except that the input field values are being treated as text objects, and therefor not displayed quite properly. I know WHAT is happening, I just haven't the slightest clue how to fix it. I've never encountered this problem before. Should the values be stuffed into a string variable first or is there some obscure conversion issue i'm unaware of? The snapshot is from the latest version of chrome... The second image shows the text in question being treated as a separate object from the text beside it... [image]
[image: Browser is seeing text as empty object/element]

```js
function chkThis() {
  var isChk = document.getElementsByName('agecert');
  var isSub = document.getElementById('submit');
  isSub.disabled = !isChk[0].checked;
}

function shPop() {
  var shPop = document.getElementById("myOlay");
  var rvwBdy = '';
  rvwBdy = '<p><b>Name:</b> ' + document.getElementById('fname').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('lname').value + '<BR />' +
    '<B>Email:</B> ' + document.getElementById('email').value + '<BR />' +
    '<B>Phone:</B> ' + document.getElementById('phone').value + '<BR />' +
    '<B>Address:</B> ' + document.getElementById('maddr').value + '</p>';

  shPop.classList.remove('dk-hidden');
  shPop.classList.add('dk-show');
  document.getElementById('reviewHere').innerHTML = rvwBdy;
}

function hdPop() {
  var hdPop = document.getElementById("myOlay");
  hdPop.classList.remove('dk-show');
  hdPop.classList.add('dk-hidden');
}
```

```css
:root {
  --dkVar: '';
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  @include pre1(box-sizing, border-box);
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #8080FF;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dk-center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dk-vertz {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.dk-hortz {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#dk-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#dk-logo {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
}

#dk-menu {
  top: 125px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background: #338833;
  text-align: center;
}

#dk-body {
  top: 210px;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  background: rgba(192, 192, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dk-logo {
  width: 400px;
}

.dk-order {
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 700px;
}

.input {
  width: 175px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #309930;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 40px;
  z-index: 9;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 8pt;
  color: red;
  z-index: 10;
}

.icon {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #309930;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #30ff30;
  background: #ffddff;
}

#inp1 {
  top: 15px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 175px;
  position: absolute;
}

#inp2 {
  top: 15px;
  left: 190px;
  width: 175px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#inp3 {
  top: 85px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 175px;
}

#inp4 {
  top: 85px;
  left: 190px;
  width: 175px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#inp5 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 25px;
}

.dk-mydiv {
  top: 210px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 750px;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  background: #bbbbff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.maddr {
  width: 400px;
  height: 125px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

button {
  color: #555555;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #99ff99;
  border: 1px solid #44aaee;
}

button:enabled {
  transition: all 250ms linear 0.0ms;
}

button:disabled {
  color: #bbbbbb;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  border: #44aaee;
  background: #555555;
  opacity: 0.75;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

button:hover:enabled,
button:focus:enabled {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #55ff55;
  border: 2px solid #44aaee;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 5px 3px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}

.product {
  width: 40px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.inplab {
  top: 15px;
  left: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}

#dk-intro {
  top: 210px;
  left: 15px;
}

#myOlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
}

#cbReview {
  min-width: 500px;
  height: 75%;
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #0055cc;
  border-radius,
  25px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dk-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.dk-show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="dk-mydiv dk-hortz">
  <form name="cbOrder" method="post" action="php/cb-cont.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="dk-order class=" dk-hortz "">
      <div id="inp1">
        <i class="icon fas fa-user"></i>
        <label for="fname" class="label">&nbsp;*Required</label>
        <input name="fname" id="fname" type="text" class="input chkIt" size="30" value="" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1" />
      </div>
      <div id="inp2">
        <i class="icon fas fa-user"></i>
        <label for="lname" class="label">&nbsp;*Required</label>
        <input name="lname" id="lname" type="text" class="input chksssaIt" size="30" value="" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2" />
      </div>
      <div id="inp3">
        <i class="icon fas fa-envelope" style="font-size: 20px;padding-top: 5px"></i>
        <label for="email" class="label">&nbsp;*Required</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="input chkIt" size="30" value="" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="3" />
      </div>
      <div id="inp4">
        <i class="icon fas fa-phone" style="font-size: 20px;padding-top: 5px;"></i>
        <label for="phone" class="label">&nbsp;</label>
        <input name="phone" id="phone" type="tel" class="input" size="10" placeholder="Phone Number" tabindex="4" />
      </div>
      <div id="inp5">
        <i class="icon fas fa-home" style="font-size: 20px;padding-top: 5px"></i>
        <label for="maddr" class="label">&nbsp;*Required</label>
        <textarea name="maddr" id="maddr" class="input maddr chkIt" cols="60" rows="5" placeholder="Mailing Address" tabindex="5"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div style="left: 50px;top: 300px;position: absolute;width: 400px;height: 150px;">
        <p style="font-size: 10pt;">NOTICE: At present, there is a limit of ten (10) items total per order.</p>
      </div>

      <div style="left: 50px;top: 325px;position: absolute;width: 200px;height: 150px;">
        <input name="whorse" id="whorse" type="number" size="3" class="input product" placeholder="Qty." value="0" tabindex="6">
        <label for="whorse" class="inplab">White Horse</label>
        <a href="img/whorse.jpg" data-lightbox="kratom"><img src="img/whorse-thumb.jpg" style="top: 50px;left:15px;" tabindex="99"></a>
      </div>

      <div style="left: 250px;top: 325px;position: absolute;width: 200px;height: 150px;">
        <input name="wbbee" id="wbbee" type="number" size="3" class="input product" placeholder="Qty." value="0" tabindex="7">
        <label for="wbbee" class="inplab">White Bumblebee</label>
        <a href="img/wbbee.jpg" data-lightbox="kratom"><img src="img/wbbee-thumb.jpg" style="top: 50px;left: 20px;" tabindex="100"></a>
      </div>

      <div style="left: 50px;top: 500px;position: absolute;width: 400px;height: 150px;">
        <input name="agecert" type="checkbox" onclick="chkThis();" style="float: left;height: 20px;width: 25px;border: 1px solid red;" tabindex="8">
        <p style="font-size: 10pt;left: 30px;position: absolute;text-align: justify;">I certify that I am 18 years of age or older and legally able to enter into a contract of purchase and/or other negotiations in the State of Louisiana. I also certify my understanding that the personal information collected from me by Cypress
          Botanicals will be used for the sole and express purpose of order fulfillment and will never be made available to any third parties.</p>
      </div>

      <div name="subres" style="width: 400px;height: 50px;top: 635px;left: 30px;position: relative;border: none;">
        <button name="submit" type="button" onclick="shPop();" id="submit" style="left: 65px;" tabindex="9" disabled="disabled">Review Order</button>
        <button name="reset" type="reset" style="left: 245px;" tabindex="10">Reset Form</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myOlay" class="dk-hidden">
  <div id="cbReview" class="dk-center">
    <p>Please review your order information to make sure everything is correct. Orders with incomplete or invalid information will not be processed. Please remember that there is an order limit of ten (10) units TOTAL. Thank you!
    </p>

    <div id="reviewHere" style="width: 75%;top: 125px;left: 25px;"></div>

    <p style="left: 15px;bottom: 15px;"><input type="button" onclick="hdPop()" value="Edit Info" /></p>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is the output you want? This looks like a CSS issue, not a Javascript issue, maybe

Comment: You see how the field values are overlapping the bold text? That's not styling, in the snapshot you can see to the right that the text is being treated as an object. Not as simple inline text

Comment: There is no css at all linked to the <P> tag, which is the only element there.. Using the element inspector in the browser it won't even see the returned values as something to click on, even though i can click on the bold text next to it. I DO know how to style a page. I'll update the image so you can see my point...

Comment: Your code snippet does not reproduce your problem and contains error(s). Please fix it.

Comment: try changing `reviewHere` style values to: `width:100%; left: 0px`

Comment: i updated the snippet but the javascript isn't working. i do have a codepen that is working and producing the same problem...  :\

https://codepen.io/Daellus/pen/GXyqjd

Comment: My point about it not being a styiling issue is the the text is getting messed up in the middle of a string. The data values themselves are the ONLY thing out of place

Comment: @Daellus you mean not surrounded by a tag or something, just text in place ?

Comment: Actually, i just figured it out... Once I removed ALL html tags from the string, everything came out in place. Does that mean i'm going to have to escape all the html character? When i use 'innerText', it produces the string just fine. innerHTML and it goes all wonky.

Comment: Maybe i didn't figure it out. Added the <P> tag back, worked fine. Closed the tag, stopped working and so did all the javascript. it also works fine until i add the bold tags back in?!?!

Comment: Stripped out all of the html tags except for the <BR> tags, which i specifically did NOT self-close. I don't know why this problem popped up because i've coded the hell out of a whole bunch of stuff like this with html inline and never had a problem. Either way, it's working now, just not as stylishly.

Comment: It was a styling thing (partially) after all. As many times as i went through it, i had overlooked my *{position: absolute;} property... So it did in fact style the bolds and the input data as separate objects. What i don't understand, though is that adding a <P> tag in the concatenated string still breaks the function. Otherwise it's working great. Thanks everyone for the opinions, help, and that edit!